# Error 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 226 pos 12: 'documentSnapshot != null': is not true. flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get next two document after getting first two documents from firestore

Here's how I'm trying to do it:-

```dart
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // collection reference
  final CollectionReference profile =
      Firestore.instance.collection('profileData');

  int pagesize = 10;

  String globaldistrict;
  DocumentSnapshot lastsnap;

  List<UserProfileData> userProfileListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return UserProfileData(
          uid: doc.data['uid'],
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
          district: doc.data['district'] ?? '',
          phoneNumber: doc.data['phoneNumber'] ?? null,
          address: doc.data['address'] ?? '',
          profilePic: doc.data['profilePic'],
          location: doc.data['location'] ?? null);
    }).toList();
  }

  //  ################## get profile list stream ##################

  Stream<List<UserProfileData>> userprofilelist(String district) {
    Query profilesquery =
        profile.orderBy('name').where('district', isEqualTo: district).limit(2);
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> profilesnap = profilesquery.snapshots();
    profilesnap.listen((event) {
      lastsnap = event.documents[event.documents.length - 1];
    });

    return profilesnap.map(userProfileListFromSnapshot);
  }

  Stream<List<UserProfileData>> moreuserprofilelist() {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> moreprofilesnap = profile
        .orderBy('name')
        .startAfterDocument(lastsnap)
        .where('district', isEqualTo: globaldistrict)
        .limit(2)
        .snapshots();

    return moreprofilesnap.map(userProfileListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

But I'm getting an error like this:-

> Error 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 226 pos 12: 'documentSnapshot != null': is not true.

How do I get the last document of first stream, So I can start the next query from there?

Comment: Maybe lastsnap is null at the moment you call the constructor. Please share what's there in line 226

Comment: I agree with Ashok, in order to fully identify what's going on here please provide the code in line 226 as the stack trace is referencing this particular section as troublesome.